# How to connect Team Foundation server on my VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Just now I received my new laptop from my office.  When I open Visual studio, in the tools I am not able to see the Connect to Team Foundation Server option. Can any body help me out how to do that? in VS2008

Comment: There's a Stack Exchange proposal for a Visual Studio ALM Q&A site that you can help to go live: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15894

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to install the Team Explorer client (prior to 2010, it is a separate install).  If you are connecting to TFS 2010 from VS2008, you'll also need the [forward compatibility update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54d&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to download and install these three things (in order) for a VS2008 client to connect to a TFS2010 server.

1. Team Explorer 2008 (if you don't already have it) from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86. *If you need a tool to mount an ISO file, [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htmBlockquote) is a good one*
2. Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E.
3. Visual Studio Team System 2008 Service Pack 1 Forward Compatibility Update for Team Foundation Server 2010 from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54d.

If the updates are not installed properly, you'll get this error when you try to connect:

```
TF253022: You must update your client with the Forward Compatibility Update in order to connect
```